# Remove Category When Post Transitions from Status Private To Public And has Specific categories already?

Tags: taxonomy

I am trying to make a function that automatically removes a category if post status changes from private to published and the post in question has 2 categories set already.

Here's the code that isn't working:

```
function remove_cat( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
if ( $old_status == 'private'  &&  $new_status = 'publish' && in_category(array('1186','1208'))) {
    $catsID = array(1186);
    wp_remove_object_terms( $postID, $catsID, 'category' ); // unset category with id 1186
} } add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'remove_cat', 10, 3 )
```

What could i be doing wrong here? I am trying to remove category 1186 from posts that have category 1186 + 1208 when the post status changes from private to public.

Thanks.

Comment: If I am correct you will find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31584174/1370973) a part you can use to achieve your goal from @PieterGoosen code (adjust to own needs when implement some in your own code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. You're not providing a post to check in `in_category()`.
2. You're calling `wp_remove_object_terms()` on `$postID`, which hasn't been set.

This code should work:

```
function my_remove_category_on_status_change( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {
    if ( $old_status == 'private' && $new_status = 'publish' && in_category( array( '1186', '1208' ), $post ) ) {
        wp_remove_object_terms( $post->ID, 1186, 'category' ); // unset category with id 1186
    }
} 
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'my_remove_category_on_status_change', 10, 3 );
```

Note:

1. I've passed the `$post` object from the function parameter to `in_category()` so that it checks if those categories are on the post that's changing status.
2. I've used `$post->ID` to give the ID of the post that's changing status to the `wp_remove_object_terms()` function.

Also, `remove_cat()` is a very generic function name, and could easily be a function in WordPress or another plugin, and could result in conflicts. I suggest being more specific and prefixing it with something unique to your project. In my example I used `my_`.

PS: Hard-coding specific category IDs locks you into those and can make maintenance somewhat difficult. I'd recommend using slugs, which are a bit more predictable, or having a setting somewhere for picking the categories related to this functionality then pulling those values into this function.